# Why won't angular events kick off when jQuery manipulates things?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Here is a plunkr sample I've created:

http://plnkr.co/edit/bgocW5Xg1q0yyiLOAR0F

I'm attempting to listen to events with angular, however they aren't invoked.  When I click on the checkbox, then the events happened.  Any idea what may be happening here?

Comment: Please do add the code in your question, I think this is good practice to have a fully understandable question by reading it entirely on SO and not have to go elsewhere to get what you really mean.

Answer (score 2):

According to AngularJS documentation - [ngChange](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angChange) :

> Evaluate given expression when user changes the input. The expression is not evaluated when the value change is coming from the model.

I assume it also counts for properties changed by `jQuery`.

I don't know if it will meet your requirements but you can simply do this :

```
$('#test').click(function(){
    $('[name="localAuth"]').click();
});
```

[See updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2QJ2bT)

Comment: Strangely enough this works.  However I'm hoping to find the reason behind this.  I'd hate to muck with a lot of plugin code that already has the `$(...).prop('checked', true)` code written every where.  I wish I could give partial credit for this answer.  I'll give it a few days and see if someone has a different response.  Otherwise you win :)

Answer (score 1):

Quoted from the [official doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3ainput.checkbox):

> ngChange(optional) – {string=} – Angular expression to be executed when input changes due to user interaction with the input element.

You have set the value inside JavaScript context, which won't trigger a browser event that Angular is listening to. So, to trigger the Angular function, you can simple put:

```
$('[name="localAuth"]').click();
```

in your jQuery event handler.

However, I don't think I'll ever want to do this in angular app. Instead, I'll bind an **anguar** handler function by using `ng-click` on the button, and change the model in the that function without involving jQuery at all.

Comment: @HighKickX I did not steal your answer! I hadn't see there was any answer when I was composing my answer. Plus, this question is kind of "what is the result of 1 + 1" type question, so you and me came up with similar answers aren't surprising.

Comment: Sorry about that, I spontaneously removed my comment after few minutes because I figured out myself this was indeed a "1+1". Excuse me again.